# Access denied for localStorage in IE11 but only in desktop mode (not in metro mode)

Tags: javascript, local-storage, windows-8.1, internet-explorer-11

So I have a site running on Adobe AEM 5.6.1 which checks if localStorage is accessible. The problem for me is it breaks with an "Access Denied" when I access the site from the Desktop version of IE11 (on a HP Elite Pad 900, running windows 8.1 Pro). On the same device it works fine using the metro mode version of IE11.

It also works fine on at least two other computers here, one native PC, one virtualbox:ed on my mac.

I know you are not allowed to access localStorage when running a local html-file but this is running on our server.

What could be different in access rights/security settings for the non-functional browser?
Is there any way of checking this programmatically with javascript?

Comment: When I run IE as Admin or disable Protected Mode the issue disappears.

Comment: This sounds like an ACL'ing bug in the broker that accesses the Local Storage file; I had this problem once on one PC after something got corrupted. Try clicking Tools > Internet Options > Advanced and click the "Reset IE to defaults" (all settings) option and reboot. If the issue isn't fixed, you'll need to contact Microsoft Product Support.

Comment: Well I don't so much care about my virtual machines test environment so much as I do about other ppl not experiencing a broken website due to this kind of local errors. But I solved that by using wrapping the code in a try catch-statement.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The way to check for local storage programmatically in JS seems to be to always use a try-catch:

http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/localstorage-pattern#comment-9

Comment: Thx! Comment 13 did the job. Because of that error my whole script wasn't working anymore, but with this snippet everything is fine again.